# jQuery Validate: Cannot Toggle Next Panel on Form Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have been struggling with this issue for over two days now.

I am trying to implement a Bootstrap accordion for my WooCommerce checkout. I managed to get the essential accordion behavior to work very well. But as I want to offer a sophisticated experience to customers, I'm trying to make this checkout form as fancy as possible (and at the same time user-friendly). In the first place, I had to use jQuery to make sure that the value of each field is retained through `localstorage` after leaving the page without form submission.

Then, I deactivated panels 2 and 3. The idea was to make each of them gradually available to the customer. You can see a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9vjcoLxh/6/

I have also added jQuery Validation to the form. As a side note, the "login/register" panel displays only if logged out. It doesn't display if the user is logged in. Instead, if the user is logged in, the next panel is toggled automatically to allow for a better flow of the checkout. I wanted to validate ONLY the second panel as it contained actual customer info (first and last name, email address, etc). The validation would be initiated on button click, and here's my snippet:

```
jQuery('#toggle-delivery').click( function() {       
  jQuery("#validate-info").validate({         
    rules: {
     phone_number: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 9
     },
     email_address: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      shipping_first_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      shipping_last_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    },
    onfocusout: function(e) {
            this.element(e);
    },
    messages: {
         phone_number: {
          required: "Please enter a valid UK phone number",
          digits: "Please enter a valid UK phone number.",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 9 characters"
         },
         email_address: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
            email: "Oops! This isn't a correct email format. Please check and try again."
         },
         shipping_first_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         },
         shipping_last_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         },
         shipping_address_1: {
          required: "Please enter a valid UK address.",
          minlength: "Please enter a valid UK address."
         }
    }
  }).form(); 
});
```

This is working well. However, I went one step further and prevented the panel with the data from collapsing and the next one from expanding if the form was not valid by adding this snippet:

```
jQuery('#toggle-delivery').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var sectionValid = true;
    var collapse = jQuery(this).closest('.panel-collapse.collapse');
    jQuery.each(collapse.find('input, select, textarea'), function(){
        if(!jQuery(this).valid()){
            sectionValid = false;
        }
    });
    if(sectionValid){
        collapse.collapse('toggle');
        collapse.parents('.panel').next().find('.panel-collapse.collapse').collapse('toggle');
    }
});
```

Again, it was working very well. However, I noticed that everything works well only if the user is logged in. If not, then the form is just validated on click, but the active panel is not collapsed + the next one is not toggled. It's as if the last snippet isn't working -- which is VERY weird since it works perfectly if the user is logged in.

I'm not jQuery/JS savvy, and not quite an WooCommerce expert either, so I cannot tell what the problem may be. I've tried lots of solutions but to no avail. I activated script debug, and nothing shows up. No errors in the JS console either. I tried it on Chrome and Firefox with the same results.

I'd really appreciate some input on a possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#toggle-delivery').click( function() {       
    jQuery("#validate-info").validate({ ...
```

You absolutely should not have the `.validate()` method within your `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin on your form and only gets called once on page load.

As far as validating each panel at a time, by default, the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore anything that's hidden.  Therefore, only the exposed panel would be validated, so you wouldn't need any special handlers to check each input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sparky for your answer. However, none of the fields are hidden -- they are the same for both logged in and logged out users. Still, the validation + toggling of next panel worked just for logged in users, so I had to drop this method and go a different route.

I have added the `btn-disabled` class to the button that was previously validating the form, along with `data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-delivery"` to make it toggle the next panel. I have added the following CSS properties to the `btn-disabled` class:

```
.btn-disabled {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
color: #ececec;
background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
```

This makes the button unclickable, so the user cannot collapse the current panel and toggle the next one. Here is my modified jQuery validation snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input').on('blur', function() {
        if (jQuery("#validate-info").validate().checkForm()) {
            jQuery('#toggle-delivery').removeClass("btn-disabled");  
        } else {
            jQuery('#toggle-delivery').addClass("btn-disabled");
        }
});
  jQuery("#validate-info").validate({         
    rules: {
     phone_number: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 9
     },
     email_address: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      shipping_first_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      shipping_last_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
     billing_phone: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 9
     },
     billing_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      billing_first_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      billing_last_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    },
    onfocusout: function(e) {
            this.element(e);
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    messages: {
         phone_number: {
          required: "Please enter a valid UK phone number",
          digits: "Please enter a valid UK phone number.",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 9 characters"
         },
         email_address: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
            email: "Oops! This isn't a correct email format. Please check and try again."
         },
         shipping_first_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         },
         shipping_last_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         },
          billing_phone: {
          required: "Please enter a valid UK phone number",
          digits: "Please enter a valid UK phone number.",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 9 characters"
         },
         billing_email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
            email: "Oops! This isn't a correct email format. Please check and try again."
         },
         billing_first_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         },
         billing_last_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         }
    }
  });
    });
```

Lines 2-8 validate each field individually. Once all fields have been filled in correctly (based on the rules I set for each of them), the `btn-disabled` class is removed and the button is enabled so the customer can collapse the current panel/toggle the next one (and thus move on to the next section of the checkout form).

There was one more aspect that was bugging me: if the user fills out all fields and refreshes the page (or navigates to another page and then comes back), even though the fields were previously validated, they will appear as invalid on the next page load (even though they are correct/valid). I have used `localstorage` to retain the data so users don't need to enter it each time. Anyway, I managed to validate previously-validated fields on page load with this snippet:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    //pre-highlight fields with values
    jQuery('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=password], select').filter(function() {
        return jQuery.trim($(this).val()) != '';
    }).blur();
});
```

Hope it helps!